# ToString() to create a Json Structure of an Object Type

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, gson

I actually have a Class named "Content" like that :

```
public class Content {

    private String Pame;
    private String Tlue;
    private String Ced;
    private String Cnce;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "...";
    }

}
```

On the other side I have a list of object of type "Content" with multiple objects in it.
My goal is to return a json formatted like this one: 
There may be multiple values in the "content field", it's why there is [].

```
{
    "result": "ok",
    "content": [{
        "pame": "value1",
        "tlue": "value2",
        "ced": "value3",
        "cnce": "1"
    }]
}
```

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
   String MyLongString = list.get(i).toString;
}
```

So my problem is :
How can I create the structure shown with the toString and the boucle For ?
How the "," at the end of each object can be put, without putting it at the last object ?

For information : I use Gson in my project
Thanks for helping

Comment: You don't use `toString` to convert to JSON. `toString` should be used for human-readable string representation of the class, and not abused for serialization. Instead, use Gson to serialize the object.

Comment: `toString` usually should return string without line separators to preserve logs format, like when we want to print list of objects in one line. To create string with specified format use tools designed to generate such format *when it is needed*, NOT in `toString()` method. Since you are using Gson take a look at [Convert Java objects to JSON strings using gson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54513956), if you want to generate multi-line version see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27893403.

Comment: `toString()` inside Content class will only have access to the attributes inside a Content object. It can't access other Content objects in list.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Json is often more human-readable than what people print in their toString methods ;)